# SUM function with data from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I am trying to use the SUM function in VBA which references another sheet. The function needs to have dynamic inputs thus I am using "Cells".

Simply adding two cells works great with the following code:

```
   Worksheets("Derived Data").Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=sheet1!" & (Cells(2, 2).Address & "+" & "sheet1!" & Cells(6, 2).Address)
```

When I try using a function such as SUM or AVERAGE or any other function, VBA interprets the function as a sub macro rather than an EXCEL function

```
Worksheets("Derived Data").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=sheet1!" & Sum(Cells(2, 2).Address & ":" & "sheet1!" & Cells(6, 2).Address)
```

Are my references wrong?

Note: the cells and columns have been fixed for the purpose of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was close try this:

```
Worksheets("Derived Data").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=sum(sheet1!" & Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(6, 2)).Address & ")"
```

Since the formula is asking for a range, using vba you need to use the range.

To make it easier to edit my preference is to split it thus but the single line above works.

```
Dim rng as Range
with sheets("Sheets1")
    set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(6, 2))
end with
Worksheets("Derived Data").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=sum(" & rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address & ")"
```

Comment: @Bro2ma Did you try this?

Comment: I have not, since the range will be dynamic. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Bro2ma This can be made dynamic easily.  What part are you wanting to make dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just don't have the correct syntax to have VBA set the formula. Try this:

```
Worksheets("Derived Data").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=Sum(sheet1!" & Cells(2, 2).Address & ":sheet1!" & Cells(6, 2).Address & ")"
```

Comment: hmm, same issue. Is there an extra parentheses?

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. I thought it may have been another issue. I didn't catch that syntax, mistake. Bro2ma -> I may the edit for you. Try it now.